# how to generate dynamically html web pages with content, when user hit submit button?

Tags: php, html

i am working on a project in which user have to ask a question through fill a form. my question is that when user fill the form and ask the question the php automatically generate the html web page. for example if user asks what is stackoverflow then url be like localhost/what-is-stackoverflow , and by clicking on this link this link show the other content which users filled.
here is my code

```html
<?php include("header.php");
require("dbconnect.php");
if(isset($_POST['post'])){

$user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
$user_name =  $_POST['user_name'];
$question_title = $_POST['question_title'];
$question_body = $_POST['question_body'];
$question_title = htmlentities($question_title);
$question_body = htmlentities($question_body);
$insert_question = mysqli_query($con,"insert into questions values('','".$user_email."','".$user_name."','".$question_title."','".$question_body."','".php_slug($question_title)."')");
}

function php_slug($question_title)
{
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/','-' , strtolower($question_title));
return $slug;

}



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="img/ico">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-7  " >
<div class="form-group ">

<form name="submit_question" action="" method="post">
<label for="user_email" class="control-label " > Enter Your Email Address We Will Mail You Answer </label>

<input type="email" class="form-control" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter Your Email We Will Mail You Answer Of Your Question"  required/>
<br >
<label for="user_name" class="control-label " > Enter Your Name </label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"  required/>
<br >
<label for="question_title" class="control-label " > Enter Your Question Subject </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="question_title" placeholder="Enter Question Subject"  required/>
<br >
<label for="question_body" class="control-label " > Question Body </label>
<textarea class="form-control pull-middle" rows="20" placeholder="Enter Post Content" name="question_body" required/> </textarea>
<div class="btn btn-group  pull-right">
<br> 
<br> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="post"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Submit Question 

</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" > </script>
<?php include("footer.php");?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
1. You have to post the all content in your <form action=""> page.
2. Get that all data in variables then replace all special characters like space, ? etc from question with '-'.
3. the create url with this updated question with the url parameters like name, email

    $url=localhost/what-is-stackoverflow?email=email@gmail.com&name=abc

4. use .htaccess file to rewrite url 

RewriteRule ^(a-zA-z)$ filename [L]

5. redirect to that url with url parameters.

    redirect($url,'refresh');

6.on that page get all url parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

`$myFile = $questiontitle.".html"; // or .php
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); // or die("error");
$stringData = "<html><head><title>".$questionbody."</title></head><body></body></html>";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);`

You can create html file and add html content programmatically by php